# Bootstrap 4 card white space after adding responsive col class, wrap elements inside div or add classes directly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4, when I add any responsive column class like "col-sm-8" directly to a "div" with class as "card", there is some whitespace added between the card border and content 
(highlighted in yellow in the below image).

[image]

Code is below:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            </div>
            **<div class="card col-sm-8">**
                <h3 class="card-header bg-primary text-white">Card...</h3>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">Number</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="radio" class="col-sm-1" name="numGuests" id="numGuests1" value="1">
                                <label for="numGuests" class="">1</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="col-sm-1" name="numGuests" id="numGuests2" value="2">
                                <label for="numGuests" class="col-form-label">2</label>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But, if I wrap the card in a "div" and add the above class to that "div", the whitespace goes away. As you can see now, the card header and content occupies all the width of the card.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            </div>
            **<div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="card">**
                    <h3 class="card-header bg-primary text-white">Card...</h3>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-2">Number</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="radio" class="col-sm-1" name="numGuests" id="numGuests1" value="1">
                                    <label for="numGuests" class="">1</label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="col-sm-1" name="numGuests" id="numGuests2" value="2">
                                    <label for="numGuests" class="col-form-label">2</label>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Why does this occur? How to know in Bootstrap whether the responsive class could be directly applied to the html element or if the element should be wrapped inside a div first?

I could not find the answer to the above in the bootstrap documentation.
For example, in the below official documentation links, the "card" example is wrapped inside a div but the  form "label" example is directly given a class "col-sm-2" without an enclosing "div".

**Snippet from Bootstrap card documentation**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

[image: Snippet from Bootstrap card documentation]
**Snippet from Bootstrap from label documentation**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

[image: Snippet from Bootstrap form label documentation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The whitespace goes away.. why does this occur?"

Because columns have left/right padding that creates the spacing (gutter) between the columns.

The [documentation states](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works)...

> "In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns"

So, the card, and any other content should be *inside* the column (`col-*`). AFAIK, the *only* place the `col-*` are combined with other classes is when using forms: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid

Comment: Thanks @ZimSystem! 1 - Why is the gutter added between card content and card border? The whole card carries a "col-sm-8" class. Also, with regards to this - "AFAIK, the only place the col-* are combined with other classes is when using forms: " - Do you mean classes like "col-form-label" are the combined classes or that the "col-**" classes can be applied to any html element inside a form (For example, the <label class="col-**"> )? Why does applying this class does not show a gutter around the label and it's border?

Comment: "Why is the gutter added between card content and card border?" Because you have `card col-sm-8` the `col-sm-8` is applying left/right padding, which is why the card should be inside the column. With forms it's by-design for label padding.